Angular Template-Driven Form: Validate Password Field Only After User Interaction
I have a form:
<input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            ngModel
            #password="ngModel"
            placeholder="Input text"
            required
          />
          <span
            *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid"
            id="passwordErrorMessage"
            class="text-danger"
            >Password is required.</span
          >
        </div>

this is a template-driven-form
The problem with validation now is that when the form is loaded- and the input is empty, it is red. The input should be red not when the form is loaded, but when the input was touched and still is empty. How to do it?
the whole code:
<h2 class="text-align-center">Login</h2>
<div class="app-plate">
  <form #loginForm="ngForm">
    <div class="login-form">
      <div>
        <div class="form__control">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <!--Use the name `email` for the form control.-->
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Input text"
            name="email"
            emailValidator
            ngModel
            #email="ngModel"
            required
          />
          <span
            *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid"
            id="emailErrorMessage"
            class="text-danger"
            >Email is required.</span
          >
        </div>
        <div class="form__control">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <!--Use the name `password` for the form control.-->
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            ngModel
            #password="ngModel"
            placeholder="Input text"
            required
          />
          <span
            *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid"
            id="passwordErrorMessage"
            class="text-danger"
            >Password is required.</span
          >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="form__action">
          <app-button button_text="Login"></app-button>
        </div>
        <div class="form__text">
          If you don't have an account you may <strong>Registration</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>


What makes the input red in the first place?

You need to change your CSS, to also validate ng-touched along with ng-invalid, this will set the red border only when the input is touched.
global_styles.scss
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
  styles: [
    `
  `,
  ],
  template: `
  <div>
    <input
      type="password"
      id="password"
      name="password"
      ngModel
      #password="ngModel"
      placeholder="Input text"
      required
    />
    <span
      *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid"
      id="passwordErrorMessage"
      class="text-danger"
      >Password is required.</span
    >
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

thanks sir! stackblitz do work fine, but my codes default input border is still red. why? i provided the whole code

@user28273827332 please try the CSS I shared, the CSS is the problem, since that adds the red border.

You can try to use the method markAsUntouched(). See the documentation: https://v17.angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsUntouched
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

const control = new FormControl();

// sets state of control as if the user did not touch it
control.markAsUntouched();

